# Qt readyRead() signal delay

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I am new to Qt and C++ as well, and trying to make a simple guitar processor with some effects.

I found some examples of low audio data processing, and they are built on `readyRead()` signals. For example, if i have a 16bit/44100 mono stream, it grabs 3528 bytes of data per signal from the device, and that means what it triggers every 44100*2/3528 = 25ms.

Is there any way to decrease this delay for a bit, or its better to use `notify()` signals instead?

Comment: I don't think `notify` signals are related to this, as they are used in the Qt property system. . .

Comment: @Mike I mean the one from audioInput class http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioinput.html#notify